# How to list all tables in sqlite.swift

Tags: swift4, sqlite.swift

Apparently I'm missing something here.
Given you want to connect to an unknown sqlite database with multiple tables, is there a way to call something like .tables on

```
let db = try Connection("path/to/db.sqlite3")
```

to retrieve a list of tables and then create a reference to it.
i tried (amongst other things)

```
 let statement = try db?.prepare("select * from sqlite_master where type='table'")
let tables = try statement!.run()
```

which returned a list of bindings, I have no idea how to deal with.